# Hide absolute div on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `div` with `position: absolute;` which is on the top right on the screen.

```
.selectState {
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #428bca;
}
```

When the user scrolls down I want to hide this `div`. How to do this with javascript or CSS?

Comment: I missed that jQuery wasn't added to the question, would delete my answer, Ferdinands answer is a way to go

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the other question is dealing with JQuery. Here's no mention of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a non-jQuery cross-browser solution:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var scrollAmount = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrollAmount > 0)
    document.querySelector('your-element').style.display = 'none';
  else
    document.querySelector('your-element').style.display = 'block';
});
```

This works for IE8+.
If you want the div to be hidden when the user already scrolled a bit, just change the number 0 to the point where you want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, the below will do it:

```
// detect when the window is being scrolled
$(window).scroll(function(){
     // if the top is more than 96px (the top offset of your element)
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 96){
        // hide the element
        $('.selectState').hide();
    }else{
        // otherwise show it
        $('.selectState').show();
    }

});
```

You could reduce it further to:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop() > 96 ?  $('.selectState').hide() : $('.selectState').show();    
});
```

Comment: OP didn't asked for jQuery, even I did the same mistake ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - hence the opening sentence ;) But you're right, in literal terms it is a JS request

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Jquery :

```
var $scrolldiv = $('#div'); // Add your div's id here
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $scrolldiv.fadeIn();
    } else if ($scrolldiv.is(':visible')) {
        $scrolldiv.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using CSS. Because CSS has no method to capture the events of the browser or window.

However, you can do that using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { // scroll events
   // hide it here using CSS or the show() hide () methods...
});
```

This way, you can get the location of the user in the DOCUMENT and change the properties too.